# Unable to override Grpc message with stream request and stream response

Tags: c#, microservices, grpc

I'm trying to create a GRPC stream service in C#. The server was created with visual studio 2022 using GRPC template in ASP.NET.CORE GPRC Service with GreeterService and it was working, but I have modified it according to my need.

Proton file:

```
service Messaging {
    rpc CreateStreaming (stream MessageRequest) 
    returns (stream MessageReply);
};
```

The MessageReply and MessageRequest are already defined in the proton file and upon building the project generating cs files in obj\Debug\net6.0\Protos\

The CreateMessaging method is also properly defined and uses all its predefined Grpc structure in Grpc auto-generated files.

In Grpc.cs file:

```
public abstract partial class MessagingBase
    {
      [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("grpc_csharp_plugin", null)]
      public virtual global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateStreaming(grpc::IAsyncStreamReader<global::GrpcServer.MessageRequest> requestStream, grpc::IServerStreamWriter<global::GrpcServer.MessageReply> responseStream, grpc::ServerCallContext context)
      {
        throw new grpc::RpcException(new grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode.Unimplemented, ""));
      }

    }
```

Now my question is I'm unable to override this method **CreateStreaming** in my Services\MessagingService.cs file as per below and it is giving an error that No suitable method found to override

```
public override Task<MessageReply> CreateStreming(MessageRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new MessageReply
            {
                Message = "Hello " + request.Message
            });
        }
```

Am I doing it right? Please assist.

Comment: I think method signature should match. I.e. the return type is different and requestStream and responseStream should be the first arguments instead of MessageRequest.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, figured it out. Now okay. Method signature was mismatching. Basically it was a duplex streaming and I was using the UNARY method signature